# What is the difference between constant declaring Global or declaring inside a function where it is used

Tags: c++, c, ada

i am declaring a constant (a large structure constant containing string) inside a function and it is used only inside this function. 
will it have any execution time impact on my program? '
They will be created every time the function is called (take more time) or only once and the reference will be used through out its life.
If i declare the constant outside the function (global) will it be faster in execution ?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to ask this and tag the question with C++, C and Ada - they're different languages and the answers are very different for e.g. C or C++ string literals (which require no runtime allocation) and C++ `std::string`s (which do dynamic runtime allocation).  So, post for one language and show us the code you're concerned about as the devil's in the details.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, declaring variables inside of a function is a great practice.  If that variable is only to be used inside of that function of course.  There won't be any performance differences between the two methods, but making the constant global may require a more creative naming scheme while the one inside the function can be generic.  It is only being used inside of that function, after all.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally move it out of the function body if any other related functions use the variable, as long as you're using namespaces.

Also if its a true constant, I believe you can declare a struct static constexpr, which means that it won't be allocated on the stack every time the function is called (static), even if you declare it inside the function body. It also means that where it can be used at compile time, it will be (constexpr).

```
#include <iostream>

namespace Test{
struct Test {
  char name[11];
  int a;
  int b;
};

static constexpr Test TEST_CONSTEXPR = {
  "test value",
  5,
  6
};
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << Test::TEST_CONSTEXPR.name << std::endl;
  std::cin.get();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`static struct` can help you setting it up once and be done with it. This will be coming from data segment and initialise during at the startup. A raw and dirty code below, but will give you some intuition.

```
#include <stdio.h>

 struct A {
     int a;
     int b;
 };

 void func(void)
 {
     static struct A a = {5,3};
     printf("FUNC: A.a: %d\n", a.a);
 }

 int main(int argc, char **argv)
 {
     static struct A a = {6,4};
     printf("MAIN: A.a: %d\n", a.a);
     func();
     return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

In Ada this is compiler dependent.  (As performance usually is.)

As "constants" are not compile-time static, a compiler may do the safe thing and evaluate the initialising expression every time the constant is declared.

If it really matters, measure what your compiler does.